# Prevent timeout using flush but page not redirecting after flush

Tags: php, timeout, flush

I am preventing timeout using flush. I've tried other methods but the load balancer settings are locked to me.

My script processes huge amount of records fully.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($stream) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stream)) {
 //updating user's ticket information 
     $unique = $row[ticketid];
     $result = $pk->updateticket($unique, $data);

//flushing to keep connection alive
flush();
ob_flush();
}
 } 

 header('Location: tickets.php');  //the redirect isn't executed - page becomes blank. Records are processed though.
```

However, I redirect the user after processing. This header location is not being executed and the page just becomes blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use header() after flushing anything because the header is already sent (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

You can use instead

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
location.replace("tickets.php");
</script>';
```

or even

```
echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=tickets.php">';
```